# Need helping creating a decorator to inforce existence of sessions data

Tags: python, django, session, decorator

I am trying to create a decorator for my Django views that makes sure certain pieces of data are in my session. If they are there, you can see the view, if they are not there, you get redirected to another view the inserts them into the session.

I am wondering:

1. Is using a decorator the right approach, or should I utilize middleware ...
2. Can someone provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A decorator definitely makes the most sense I think. Check out the `@login_required` decorator's code:

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(login_url or
                                                        settings.LOGIN_URL)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(path, login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator


def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated(),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```